# Looking for a statistics formula to show deviations from zero

Tags: statistics

I'm looking for a formula to show deviations from zero. I have a data set with values that that is normalized to positive real numbers where zero is perfect and higher is worse. I need a statistical formula that gives me a number over the whole set. I'm now using standard deviation, and it is showing me some interesting results, but as I understand standard deviation normalizes on the average of the set. I need it to use zero as the basis.

Comment: If your positive numbers are $x_1, \dots, x_n$ then you can use something like $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i^2}$?

Comment: My math abilities are nowhere close enough to be able to understand this. Can you give me a WikiPedia page or a layman's explanation of this formula, maybe as an answer :).

Comment: That formula _is_ the standard deviation, but around zero, not around the average ...

Comment: Thanks. I've applied it (someone helped :) ) and it looks just fine. If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure deviations from zero, you can just use the standard deviation around zero, and not around the average. The formula will be:
$$
       \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}
$$